# Random collectable items falling in the Camera View but not in the Game View

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a tutorial to make random GoodItems spawn from spawn points.
I see them falling at the spawnpoints in the Scene but not in the game view, they are just invisible. What's going on?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    public GameObject goodItems;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < spawnPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            if (randomIndex != i)
            {
                Instantiate(goodItems, spawnPoints[i].position, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: By any chance, your Game-view camera is not aligned to face the objects? Double-check that the view frustum points toward the `goodItems` and that they're not being obstructed.

Comment: The camera should be facing the objects! I have other objects next to the instantiated one and they show up fine.

Comment: Double-check the [LayerMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) of the instantiated objects ? It may be that your `Camera` is set to not render their assigned layer.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, but perhaps the z-axis values of the *spawnPoints* objects are behind camera's z-axis value or camera's *near clipping plane*, or far away from camera's *far clipping plane*

Comment: Oh my god so the SpawnPoints object had the Z layer super weird but when I set it to 0 it made the item show up in the game! This is strange though since the spawn points themselves within the SpawnPoints object had a z of 0, so I thought it wouldn't make that big of a difference.

Comment: Happy to hear that you find the reason for your problem.
Unfortunately, that's normal to have a lot of weird things happening in development in general, specially in Unity
You have to embrace that 